# knockouts visible function not working as expected

Tags: knockout.js

I'm developing a SPA app that list invoices. Using the "visible" function the app switches between a list view and an edit view. The edit view allows the user to add line items to the invoice. After adding a line item, if I switch back to the listing and then back into edit view, the last item I added is missing. Is it missing from the viewModel? Do I need to update the viewModel somehow? If I do a refresh, the recently added line item shows up.
After adding a new line item and returning to list view, here's the "Edit" row function.

```
InvoiceEditView: function (id) {
    invID = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(id);
    this.getLineItems([]); // Clear array
    this.newLineItems([]); // Clear array
    this.InvoiceViewMode(false);
    this.InvoiceEditMode(true);
    var obj = ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.invoices(), function (item) {
        return item.InvoiceID === invID;
    });
    viewModel.InvoiceID(obj[0].InvoiceID);
    viewModel.Customer(obj[0].Customer);
    viewModel.InvoiceTotal(obj[0].InvoiceTotal);
    viewModel.radioSelectedStatus(obj[0].Status);
    viewModel.RequestedBy(obj[0].RequestedBy);
    viewModel.StartDate(obj[0].StartDate);
    viewModel.EndDate(obj[0].EndDate);

    // build line items array
    var larray = [];
    larray = ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.lineItems(), function (item) {
        return item.InvoiceID === invID;
    });
    //console.log("larray:", larray);
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(larray, function (item) {
        var pid = 0;
        var total = 0;
        lid = item.LineID;
        pid = item.ProductID;
        //console.log("lid:", lid);
        //console.log("pid:", pid);
       var productData = [];
        productData = ko.utils.arrayFirst(viewModel.products(), function (p) {
            return p.ProductID === pid;
        });
        //console.log("productData:", productData);
        //var lineItem = function ((lineid, productName, unit, quantity, price, extPrice, filledDate, filledBy) {
        viewModel.getLineItems.push(new comboLineItem(lid, productData.Name, productData.Unit, item.Quantity, productData.Price, item.ExtendedPrice, item.FilledDate, item.FilledBy));
        total += parseFloat(item.ExtendedPrice);
    });
    //viewModel.currInvTotal(total);
    //console.log(viewModel.getLineItems());
}
```

Comment: Without the source code, it's hard to say something...

Comment: I'm trying to getting a fiddle working, but I figure someone out there has probably experienced this before. I'll post a link asap.

Comment: It could be that you're binding to a copy of the array, or maybe you added parenthesis somewhere you shouldn't and it's bound to the underlying array instead of an observable array. Lots of possibilities without seeing the code.

Comment: In the code above, I clear the array and re-parse it.

Comment: it might be the lineItems observable array has not been reloaded from the database. I will add that code to see if that's it.

Comment: I added another push statement that adds a row to the lineItem array very close to the "getLineItem" array but without any product data. The problem is that I don't know the LineID value because that's an auto-increment int created by SQL server. Do I have any options at this point or am I forced to do a refresh?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I needed to retrieve the last record (line item) posted to the server and push that data to the lineItems array.